# Prestashop: Override function from a module, across different PS versions

Tags: overriding, prestashop

I have a question a little bit advanced in regards to function override for a core class from a module.

Standard way is to place the override in /modules/my_module/override/classes/XXX.php and PS install() function will handle all the rest.

But what if the function that is being overridden has different parameters between PS versions? This will require different override files and a way to use the correct one upon install. But is there a way to accomplish this automatically?

One way that I was thinking is to leave the folder /modules/my_module/override/classes/ empty and on install function, before calling parent::install() - first to copy the correct file based on the actual PS version, where the module is installed.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Hi @CristiC, your solution should be a good way... At the moment PrestaShop don't manage this 'problem' :)